# Stuck in Welcome to Xamarin Forms After I Made A Changes

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm creating my static mobile app and I'm using Xamarin Studio in Mac OS X El Capitan.

I removed the default homepage which is the "Welcome to Xamarin Forms" and replace it with my own homepage.

When I debug it in my iOS Emulator, it updates and run the same way that I want but when I choose the Droid project and allowed it to be my Startup Project and I run it, it stuck in the "Welcome to Xamarin Form!" and none of my changes has been added.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your solution. Also delete the existing application from your device or emulator. Then try again.

Comment: I already done it. But, do I really need to uninstall the application in my physical device every time I make changes? :/ That's odd.

Comment: You don't need to do that all the time. But when such things happen that's one way to solve your problem. And what is your default page?

Comment: Thank you :) I clean and rebuild it. Thanks for the help! Please create your "Answer Your Question" so I can mark this as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and rebuild your solution. Also delete the existing application from your device or emulator. Then try again.

Comment: Thank you so much! God bless! + :)